# jquery doesn't apply click function on desktop width website, but does on mobile width

Tags: jquery, css

I have a navigation that should get a class applied with jquery on click.
It works on mobile, and landscape(mobile) but it doesn't on desktop width.
I changed it to just alert('hi') instead of the class and it still works on mobile/landscape but not on desktop. 
I'm sitting at this problem for hours now and just can't see the missing part.

What could be the issue?

I tried to narrow down the problem, and figured out that it has something to do with the application of a class trough the .click function.

I made sure that everything is linked properly.
I have the script linked(otherwise the mobile version wouldnt work either)

I tried to apply the click function on an image in the desktop version. Which worked. It did show me an alert message.

For some reason it just doesnt apply on the buger_button_wrapper on desktop.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#burger_button_wrapper').click(function() {
    alert("hi");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="burger_button_wrapper">
  <div class="burger_button">Menu</div>
</div>
```

On click of #burger_button_wrapper an alert('hi') should appear.

Comment: Is the CSS styles of the app the same for desktop than for mobile? It occurs to me that in desktop version there might be a layer or element extending ABOVE the burger button, being that element the one that is actually being click in desktop. You could try to right click the burger button on desktop and "inspect element", and check if the selected element is the one with the id "burger_button_wrapper".

Comment: Can you proofread your question? you mention desktop and mobile sometimes where I'm not sure if you actually mean desktop or mobile. Also, you mention the class burger_button_wrapper even though your HTML shows that you're using the ID of burger_button_wrapper

Comment: @Bruno García that was the first thing that came to my mind. I checked it but it is the right element.

Comment: @Jack Marchetti  oh the last sentene showed it as a class but of course i meant it to be the id. It works on mobile query but not on desktop query.